# TFS 2013 remove state from Work Type

Tags: tfs

I want to remove a state from the "Task" work type. For that I would have to check if any Work Item is assigned to this state. If so, change them to a different state, and then remove this state.

Can anyone please advise how to remove a state from a work type. Also how to change states of multiple Work items.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f) to edit the task work item template.

For bulk editing work items you can check [Bulk modify work items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409280.aspx); you'll have to run a query that is displaying all task with that state then bulk edit them.